# rails webpack compilation hangs in production at 78% [0] chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, babeljs, webpacker, terser

I am using Rails 5 with webpack, trying to compile for production because the assets don't show up in production.

If I try `NODE_ENV=production rake webpacker:compile`, then it hangs at `Compiling...`.

After reading [Compiling in production fails silently and isn't verbose enough](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1824), I tried `NODE_ENV=production bin/webpack --progress --config config/webpack/production.js`. It hung at `78% [0] chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin`

I read this https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/other/tree-shaking#issues, but I'm not sure how to switch Rails webpack to use Babel Minify instead of Terser.

Any help changing Rails to use the [Babel Minify plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/babel-minify-webpack-plugin/) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to make the change in the environment you'd like to use Babel Minify with.

If it's for the production environment, your `config/webpack/production.js` needs to look similar to:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'
const environment = require('./environment')
const BabelMinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin')

environment.config.optimization.minimizer = [ new BabelMinifyPlugin() ]

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

This assumes you added `babel-minify-webpack-plugin` as a dependency in your `package.json` file.

If you want to try disabling `collapse_vars` like the [linked article](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/other/tree-shaking#issues) points out in option 3, your config file should look similar to:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'
const environment = require('./environment')
const UglifyJSPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin")

environment.config.optimization.minimizer = [
  new UglifyJSPlugin({
    uglifyOptions: {
      collapse_vars: false
    }
  })
]

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

This assumes you added `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` as a dependency in your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with erb-loader. Found the solution in this [comment](https://github.com/usabilityhub/rails-erb-loader/issues/47#issuecomment-434138107). There is some problem with erb-loader and spring interaction which causes the freeze.
To fix it, just need to add

```
env:        {
    ...process.env,
    DISABLE_SPRING: 1,
  }
```

to options in erb-loader config(config/webpack/loaders/erb.js),, so the entire config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.erb$/,
  enforce: 'pre',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'rails-erb-loader',
    options: {
      runner: (/^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'ruby ' : '') + 'bin/rails runner',
      env:        {
        ...process.env,
        DISABLE_SPRING: 1,
      },
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have been running into an issue similar to this one, [Compiling never completes Rails 5.2, ERB and compile: true](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1534). I removed the erb loader from my project and `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` completes. I also no longer get warnings about chunk size.